# Merging JSON and overwriting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to be able to merge an object (**obj1**) in JSON with a another object (**obj2**). obj2 is a subset of obj1, so it will never have any other extra values.

```
var obj1 = {
    "name":"bob",
    "age":99,
    "occupation":"builder"
}

var obj2 = {
    "name":"Joe",
    "age":23,
}
```

When the are merged, the values from the smaller object should replace the values in the larger class like so.

```
var obj1 = {
    "name":"Joe",
    "age":23,
    "occupation":"builder"
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this in jQuery or Javascript?

I tried **$.merge(..)** but that didn't seem to work. I could write a for(..) loop, but there must be a simpler solution.

Comment: Pretty easy to just write your own function that compares the keys and overwrites existing properties of the larger object with the smaller object

Comment: How are you using `$.extend()`? [It should work](http://jsfiddle.net/kbx0evos/).

Comment: yes. extend does work. Put it as an answer and i can accept it. Not sure why it didnt work for me

Comment: Don't use `$.merge`, it's used for different purposes. You need `$.extend`: `$.extend(obj1, obj2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with $.extend the second object replaces the values in the first object: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

```js
var obj1 = {
    "name":"bob",
    "age":99,
    "occupation":"builder"
}

var obj2 = {
    "name":"Joe",
    "age":23,
}

jQuery.extend(obj1, obj2);
for (var j in obj1) {
        alert(j + " " + obj1[j]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

gives:
 {
    "name":"Joe",
    "age":23,
    "occupation":"builder"
}

will give the response in your answer or if you want the object with less values to always replace you can use:

```js
var obj1 = {
        "name":"bob",
        "age":99
    }

    var obj2 = {
        "name":"Joe",
        "age":23,
        "occupation":"builder"
    }
    if(Object.keys(obj1).length>Object.keys(obj2).length)
    jQuery.extend(obj1, obj2);
else
  jQuery.extend(obj2,obj1);
    for (var j in obj1) {
            alert(j + " " + obj1[j]);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

gives:
 {
    "name":"bob",
    "age":99,
    "occupation":"builder"
}

Answer (score 1):

```
function mergeEm(bigger, smaller) {

  for (var property in smaller) {
    bigger[property] = smaller[property];
  }
  return bigger;
```

}